# Adding DOI in APA style reference list of elsarticle class

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, elsarticle, doi

I prepared an article using elsarticle class (elsevier) template, however the journal required the references to (i) cited as author-year within the text and (ii) listed alphabetically by author name in the reference list section. For this I used the APA style bibliography (along with authoryear document class). However, in the reference list the DOI is not included, provided I already added DOI for some of the references in the bibtex library. Is there any easy workaround for this problem?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. There is no such thing as an `authoryear` documentclass. The `apa` bibliography style is very old and doesn't know anything about DOIs. For a true APA style  use `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` along with the `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`.  However, the Elsevier classes provide an author year style of their own, `elsarticle-harv.bst` so if you are submitting to an Elsevier journal you should probably use `\usepackage{natbib}\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}` as recommended.

Comment: @AlanMunn 
By authoryear I meant as, 
    \documentclass[authoryear,preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
your suggestion of using        elsarticle-harv is working fine
    \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

Comment: Ok. I'll add that as an answer. It would have been helpful if you had shown a minimal document that showed what you were doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elsevier document classes provide three bibliography styles to be used with them. Their Author/Year style is `elsarticle-harv`, so that is the correct bibliography style to use. The class will load the `natbib` package itself. For more details see the  [documentation for the class](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/elsdoc).

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\begin{document}
...
\bibliography{<yourbibfile>}
\end{document}
```